# Stone, Brick, Concrete. Which material is the heaviest per cubic inch?

Tags: concrete, brick, masonry, stone

I'm building a mobile fence and and have limit space to hold down my poles.

I wanted to know what is heaviest material per cubic inch.

Stone, Brick, Concrete... or What?

[image]

This is the limited space I have to work with. 10 inches x 5 inches x 2 inches

Comment: Granite. But, that which you can work with? Concrete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That kind of information is easy to find with google.  Here's one of the first that came up for me:
http://www.rfcafe.com/references/general/density-building-materials.htm

Concrete - 150 lbs/ft^3

Brick - 120 lbs/ft^3

Crushed stone - 100 lbs/ft^3

Limestone - 171 lbs/ft^3

If you really want some weight, go with cast iron - 450 lbs/ft^3

You're diagram shows 100 in^3 which is 0.058 ft^3

Concrete will be the easiest to work with in this application, but would come to just 8.7 lbs  A bit more then a gallon of water (8.3 lbs)

Comment: And lead is even heavier at 709 according to http://www.coolmagnetman.com/magconda.htm But probably not a good idea due to toxicity.

Comment: @manassehkatz If toxicity isn't a problem, I recommend depleted uranium, which gets you almost 1200lb/ft^3,

Comment: Lol ... username checks out